# How do I allocate data to memory in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips

I am a beginner in MIPS Assembly language programming and I am currently learning to work with Pointers as well as the lw and sw instructions.  In order to practice I want to set some data in memory and write some instructions that offset a base address to see how it works.  Any help on how to set a .s file up that will do this would be great!

Cheers,
Samuel Welker

Comment: You forgot to mention which assembler you use. For starters, you can just declare some stuff in your data/bss sections using the appropriate directives such as `foo: .int 42`.

Comment: My apologies, I am using the QTSPIM simulator.

Comment: Could you post an example of a file that allocates some data to memory that I can then store into some registers and work with?  I can't find anywhere in my book with a file like this.

Comment: Many examples even right here on SO. [Here is one of my old answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19105127/547981). [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13655852/547981) is possibly even better.

Comment: Wow... Now that's broad.